# SQL Update, Set value has ' (single quote) and '' Double quote How do i proceed?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm doing an update but the value has ' and " quotes,
How do I proceed?

This is how my query looks like

```
Update Users
set info = '[user{"LinkAction('togglemore', 'companies','jobs')","IsVisible":true}]'  
where user like '%admin%'
```

How do i make the SET to consider everything in the ' single quote '

Comment: Thank you for your response! DineshDB

Comment: If you are doing that from within your application, you should use a PreparedStatement with bind variables - how exactly you do that depends on the programming language you are using

Comment: I'm currently just doing a simple update.. nothing too complex ... i have tried using \' but its destroys my value i'm updating

Comment: The need for a prepared statement and bind variables is independent of the "complexity" of the statement. You should do it for security reasons and a nice side-effect of that is, that do not need to care about escaping of special characters

Answer (score 2):

You can use two single quote `''`

```
 Update Users
    set info = '[user{"LinkAction(''togglemore'', ''companies'',''jobs'')","IsVisible":true}]'  
    where user like '%admin%'
```

*sqlfiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/402e8/1*

Comment: Hi! I actually used ' ' but there is a conflict as the value has so many ' (single quotes)

Comment: Could you explain there is a conflict as the value has so many ' (single quotes) mean:)

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near 's'.  that's because i have so many ' inside " " e.i " user's " etc

Comment: Is your `updated` data the same as the throw error data?It seem not the same. because I can't find the `user's` word in your question data.  I add a sqlfiddle in my answer